# Grails: "where" query with optional associations

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, where-clause

I'm trying to run a "where" query to find a domain model object that has no association with another domain model object or if it does, that domain model object has a specific property value.  Here's my code:

```
query = Model.where({
  other == null || other.something == value
})
def list = query.list()
```

However, the resulting list only contains objects that match the second part of the OR statement.  It contains no results that match the "other == null" part.  My guess is that since it's checking a value in the associated object its forcing it to only check entries that actually have this associated object.  If that is the case, how do I go about creating this query and actually having it work correctly?

Comment: Updated answer using DetachedCriteria. But I suggest using the former approach of withCriteria if feasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a LEFT JOIN in order to look for null associations. By default Grails uses inner join which will not be joined for null results. Using `withCriteria` as below you should get the expected results:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

def results = Model.withCriteria {
    other(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN){
        or{
            isNull 'id'
            eq 'something', value
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I know aliasing is not possible in DetachedCritieria where one would try to specify the join as in `createCriteria/withCriteria`. There is an [existing defect regarding adding the functionality to DetachedCriteria](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10248). Just adding the work around for where query as mentioned in defect.

```
Model.where {
    other {
        id == null || something == value
    }
}.withPopulatedQuery(null, null){ query -> 
    query.@criteria.subcriteriaList[0].joinType = CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN
    query.list()
}
```

I would rather use `withCriteria` instead of the [above hack](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/grails/gorm/DetachedCriteria.groovy#L912).

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
query = Model.where({
  isNull( other ) || other.something == value
})
```

If that wouldn't work, try something like:

```
  other.id == null || other.something == value
```

UPDATE:

or with good'ol criteria query:

```
list = Pack.withCriteria{
  or{
    isNull 'other'
    other{ eq 'something', value }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ... just tried them and unfortunately they produce the same result ... the first part of the OR statement is ignored. :(

Comment: try using the good 'ol `withCriteria()` method. I think it should work - see the update

Comment: Thanks, but after trying the updated suggestion I still get the same problem.